# iOS App, embedded provisioing profile of framework produces error ITMS-90159 / 90179

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile, sdk, microstrategy

We use the `Microstrategy SDK 10.5` with `XCode 7.3.1` for developing an iOS App.

The built and internal test on our devices works fine, but we are not able to upload the App to the store due to the attached issues.

[image]

As I understand, the problem is related Microstrategy Framework and its embedded provisioning profile. While uploading we try to sign the app with our company certificate and add our provisioning profile, but the framework uses its own embedded provisioing profile, therefore the upload fails.

If we remove this framework the upload process to the store would works.

Any ideas or hints to solve this problem?

Kind Regards, 
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest option is getting Microstrategy to deliver their mobile SDK as an unsigned framework. Xcode doesn't require framework targets to be signed. They can and should be signed in the embedding frameworks build phase of an application target.

If needed or preferred, you can also re-sign the framework yourself:

1. See if the Microstrategy SDK framework contains a provisioning profile (most likely named embedded.mobileprovision). If so, delete it.
2. Re-sign the framework with the command `codesign --deep --force --sign "<< Your distribution identity name here >>" path/to/microstrategy.framework`.

Comment: Hello thank you very much!

The deletion of the embedded.mobileprovision worked fine. Afterwards we were able to sign the complete app with our company certificates.

Do we need to perform your step 2. in addition? What is the adventage to re-sign the framework?

Kind regards, Alex

Comment: Was the upload successful this time? If so, then the second step is not necessary. The Microstrategy framework has to be re-signed if Xcode doesn't properly replace the signature in the embedding build phase.

Answer (score 0):

Likely not the cause of your problem, but for future readers who might get here having googled for the error number ITMS-90159 : you will also get this same error if you have mistakenly created the app record in iTunes Connect under a different team than the one you are using to code-sign your app.